# Terraform Cloud REST API: correct payload to create a run

Tags: powershell, rest, terraform

I place before I'm new to Terraform and I'm still in phase of study and investigation.

Following Terraform Cloud **REST API** documentation [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cloud/api/run.html), I'm trying to send an HTTP request using **PowerShell**.

```bsh
$token = '******************************************************************************************'
$workspaceId = 'ws-bbaGwqP1yANww4va'
$configVersionId = 'cv-WQBetTmvfiiPmeb7'
$payload = @"
{
    "data": {
      "attributes": {
        "is-destroy": false,
        "message": "Custom message",
        "target-addrs": []
      },
      "type":"runs",
      "relationships": {
        "workspace": {
          "data": {
            "type": "workspaces",
            "id": "$workspaceId"
          }
        },
        "configuration-version": {
          "data": {
            "type": "configuration-versions",
            "id": "$configVersionId"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
"@

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://app.terraform.io/api/v2/runs' `
    -Method Post `
    -ContentType 'application/vnd.api+json' `
    -Headers @{
        Authorization = "Bearer $token"
    } `
    -Body $payload `
    -UseBasicParsing

$response | Write-Host
```

I got a different response that one stated in docs and an error too.

```bsh
Invoke-WebRequest : {"errors":[{"status":"404","title":"not found"}]}
At C:\Users\coder\Dropbox\Hacking\Terraform\cloud\run.ps1:32 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://app.terraform.io/api/v2/r ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
{"data":{"id":"ws-bbaGwqP1yANww4va","type":"workspaces","attributes":{"name":"d4s-test_workspace","auto-apply":false,"created-at":"2020-06-01T12:21:25.233Z","environment":"default","locked":false,"queue-all-runs":false,"terraform-version":"0.12.26","working-directory":"","speculative-enabled":true,"allow-destroy-plan":true,"auto-destroy-at":null,"latest-change-at":"2020-06-01T13:49:05.681Z","operations":true,"vcs-repo":{"branch":"","ingress-submodules":false,"identifier":"dev4side/Dev4side%20-%20Intranet.ai/_git/test-terraform_cloud","display-identifier":"dev4side/Dev4side - Intranet.ai/test-terraform_cloud","oauth-token-id":"ot-w1guRPT33CDwvZxW","webhook-url":"https://app.terraform.io/webhooks/vcs/04722e54-590d-48b9-a006-878c42c201a3"},"vcs-repo-identifier":"dev4side/Dev4side - Intranet.ai/test-terraform_cloud","permissions":{"can-update":true,"can-destroy":true,"can-queue-destroy":false,"can-queue-run":false,"can-queue-apply":false,"can-update-variable":true,"can-lock":false,"can-unlock":false,"can-force-unlock":false,"can-read-settings":true},"actions":{"is-destroyable":true},"description":null,"file-triggers-enabled":false,"trigger-prefixes":[],"source":"tfe-ui","source-name":null,"source-url":null},"relationships":{"organization":{"data":{"id":"d4stest","type":"organizations"}},"current-run":{"data":{"id":"run-TcWXjJfVEUYgEuuq","type":"runs"},"links":{"related":"/api/v2/runs/run-TcWXjJfVEUYgEuuq"}},"latest-run":{"data":{"id":"run-TcWXjJfVEUYgEuuq","type":"runs"},"links":{"related":"/api/v2/runs/run-TcWXjJfVEUYgEuuq"}},"current-state-version":{"data":{"id":"sv-w6zKbRPdUyQqackG","type":"state-versions"},"links":{"related":"/api/v2/workspaces/ws-bbaGwqP1yANww4va/current-state-version"}}},"links":{"self":"/api/v2/organizations/d4stest/workspaces/d4s-test_workspace"}}}
```

I was not able to understand the purpose of `data.attributes.target-addrs` and why I get a **404** status code.

I'm sure I'm missing some concept. Can someone please explain me or link a specific part of Terraform docs?

Thanks for anyone who'll help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the API token you are using has the right access level.

Follow the Terraform link to know about access levels-https://www.terraform.io/docs/cloud/users-teams-organizations/api-tokens.html#access-levels.